# Start app when opening project in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to have VS code run several commands and start an app (or several) upon opening a project?

The ideal case for what I am doing would be:

1. Open the project in vscode
2. Runs a particular ngrok command
3. Starts Mongo
4. Starts an NPM script

The goal being to open the project in VS code and just get to work instead of running through several setup steps.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_custom-tasks

Comment: Have done some testing on this, and it looks like a strong option to offload about 80% of the overhead of opening / starting my project, although not as completely passive as the custom extension option appears to have the potential to be. Will probably go with this for the time being. Waiting on feedback from Matt as well on the possibility of a boilerplate extension to get up and running with extension activation events.

Comment: @HansPassant this ended up being the way I went and has been working great the last week or so. If you add you comment as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: It is just link soup, do share what you actually did to leverage the feature in your own post.  And mark it as the answer, it ought to be the right one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update August 12, 2019**

@Andrew Wolfe had a great point in the comments, asking about [workspace activation events](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/activation-events). As I implement similar configurations in future projects, I will probably go in that direction.

**Original answer:**

Ended up using @HansPassant's solution: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_custom-tasks

So something similar to this in my `.vscode/tasks.json` file:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Launch Ngrok",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "ngrok http -subdomain=<SUBDOMAIN> <PORT>",
      "windows": {
        "command": "ngrok http -subdomain=<SUBDOMAIN> <PORT>"
      },
      "group": "none",
      "presentation": {
        "reveal": "always",
        "panel": "new"
      }
    },
    {
      "label": "Launch App",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "npm start",
      "windows": {
        "command": "npm start"
      },
      "group": "none",
      "presentation": {
        "reveal": "always",
        "panel": "new"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I also saved my project as a named Workspace, so that I can quickly identify which project I am looking at as I cycle through open projects.

Added a similar `tasks.json` file in `.vscode` for every project, and then just use the command palette to kick off each task every time I want to work on something.

Each app has different requirements for dependencies which need to be running simultaneously, some start via node locally, some I am starting on a remote server, some I need to have TypeScript always running, and then Rsync to the remote dev server (and bound the Rsync task to cmd+option+s for quick updates, [more here](https://medium.com/@olegsmetanin/containerized-development-recipe-rsync-with-remote-development-server-in-vscode-49d9cb9db7f5)).

This solution makes all of the above a breeze, and saves me from having to remember the magic incantation to get each project running every time.

Comment: so you didn't try some sort of workspace activation event?

Comment: Didn't feel the need to dig further on this for the project in question, but workspace activation events look great. Will add mention of them to my answer.

Answer (score 19):

Add this into your .vscode/tasks.json in a project folder to run a script or execute a command when you open the folder in VS code:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Launch app", // Name of task
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "npm start", // Enter your command here
      "group": "none",
      "presentation": {
        "reveal": "always",
        "panel": "new"
      },
      "runOptions": {
        "runOn": "folderOpen"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you need to enable automatic tasks:

1. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and type `> Tasks: Manage Automatic Tasks in Folder`
2. Hit Enter then choose "Allow Automatic Tasks in Folder".

Your task will execute next time you open VS Code in that folder.

Comment: how do i find this?

Comment: @magicgum in your project root there is a folder called .vscode, create a file called tasks.json and paste the JSON from above

Answer (score 2):

Yes, extensions have access to node so they can run pretty much any scripts. You can also launch shell scripts within the VS Code terminal using the VS Code extension API.

Use [activation events](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/activation-events) to start your extension when a user loads a workspace. The `workspaceContains` is probably the best fit.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Taking a look at both this and the custom tasks option. Looks like to pursue this I would need to at least make a basic boilerplate extension, then customize the package.json file with the activation events you mentioned? If so, seems like a custom extension would certainly do the job, and perhaps in a more passive way than custom tasks, but with a lot more code to maintain and probably requires more attention / dev time than I can give to it right now. Do you know of a relatively minimal way to get up and running with a barebones extension that just does what you describe?