# opening vscode to latest directory in specified path

Tags: visual-studio-code

**Is it possible to have vscode automatically open the newest folder within a specific path?**

For example, with this configuration:

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "\\\\FromABC\\Archive",
            "name":"From ABC"
        },
        {
            "path": "\\\\FromXYZ\\Archive",
            "name":"From XYZ"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would expect these folders in the workspace to be pointing to \07\07 because those were created today:

```
\\\\FromABC\\Archive\\2021\\07\\07
\\\\FromXYZ\\Archive\\2021\\07\\07
```

**Is it possible to create a workspace where the folders are opened to the latest folder within each configured path?**

Comment: I just want to clarify what it is you're asking exactly. What do you mean by automatically, like when VSCode opens? or when using a keybinding? And do you want to open the folder that was most recently added to the directory, or the folder that was most recently modified in the directory?

Comment: To just give a clear start to anyone and everyone who wants to attempt to find a solution for this. The obvious first topic to research is automatically opening files. First, it needs to be established what auto-opening means, and if VSCode is able to provide that sort of auto-opening, if that makes sense. Also, sometimes you can use your platform, especialy if your on linux, to open different directories & files with ease.

Comment: Agree with @JAY-DEV that the prompt is too unclear right now. What is the level of automation you're expecting? Is running a batch file that opens the newest folder in VSCode sufficient or do you absolutely need the automation to happen inside VSCode itself?

Comment: In Linux it should be easy to wrap the binary for vscode in a shellscript to provide it with the right folder argument. But I will not write the code for it unless I know this would be an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 2):

There's not enough information in the original question to fully answer it, however, I can suggest a few avenues of attack

- **Custom Command** (error-prone and picky)
- **Modify Upstream Process** (likely the best overall)
- **Combining Both** (perhaps the best for your immediate case)

---

### Creating a Custom Command

Create a new command per https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/command#creating-new-commands

VSCode Commands Listing: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands

- new command

  - detect latest folder through whatever logic you like
  - call `vscode.openFolder` to navigate to it
- call your custom command through Activation Events (`activationEvents`) at either `onStartupFinished` or `*` (Start Up; less-preferable, but may be required to avoid confusing the editor)
  https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/activation-events#Start-up

Check out [Start app when opening project in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51049955/start-app-when-opening-project-in-vs-code) for a few answers related to this

---

### Modifying the Upstream Process

Cutting the gordian knot, it's likely some process (perhaps a human) is creating the directories for you

Change the upstream process so when it creates the directories, it also creates/updates a link to the directory labeled something like `latest`

```
/FromABC/Archive/2021/06/03
/FromABC/Archive/2021/07/05
/FromABC/Archive/2021/07/07
/FromABC/Archive/latest  --> /FromABC/Archive/2021/07/07
/FromXYZ/Archive/2020/04/12
/FromXYZ/Archive/2021/08/18
/FromXYZ/Archive/latest  --> /FromXYZ/Archive/2021/08/18
```

Then you can always refer to the `latest` directory and it will always be correct

This is quite common when something can change frequently, but another process is expecting a static path and/or has no way to know the schedule of change

I don't have any Windows systems to try this out with and you may be able to create a regular shortcut for this .. however, you may need a Junction (soft-link) or Hard Link to convince VSCode that the directory is a real directory
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/hard-links-and-junctions

This also provides an opportunity to include *more* files, such a beta versions of some software, which it's desirable to package into the same directory structure, but not truly the `latest` stable!

---

### Combining Both

If your upstream process is either not modifiable (or some manual process it's annoying or error-prone to add extras steps to) you can likely combine both solutions to get what you really want

Use the `*` Action Event to call a script to detect and create the new directory - create a binary or PowerShell script to make your link

In this and with the upstream change, just point VS Code to the `latest` directory and it shouldn't mind

Answer (score 1):

Not sure on which platform you are, I assume windows, but essentially similar.

Instead of trying to get VSCode to open the latest folder, I would create a script that updates a softlink for each folder to the latest subfolder in it. Then you can point VSCode to the softlink, which can be updated whenever needed to the latest subfolders.